# Python - How to iterate over df and perform calculation for last 3 years

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, correlation

I have a dataframe that has 10 years worth of data. Starting with the first week I want to calculate the correlation of the last 3 years for each company. Then I want to move to the next week and calculate the correlation for the previous 3 years from that date. I then want to append all the results into a single dataframe. I have the calculation for the first date, but I don't know how to do it for the entire dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(['Date','Company'])
df = df.sort_values('Date', ascending = False)
dffinal = df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values(df.index,0).unique()[:157]].groupby('Company') 
['Xvalues'].corr(df['Yvalues']).to_frame()
dffinal.columns = ['correlation']
dffinal['Date'] = df.index.max()[0] 
dffinal = dffinal.set_index('Date', append=True)
dffinal.reorder_levels(['Date','Company'])
dffinal.head()
```

Results:

[image]

Original Dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I created an empty list and used a for loop to create a new dataframe and then appended the results into a new dataframe:

```
# create emtpy list
appended_data = []

for x in range(0,419):
    # New df will 3 years worth of data
    dfnew = df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values(df.index,0).unique()[x:157+x]]
    # Calculate correlation
    dfcorr = dfnew.groupby('Company'['Xvalues'].corr(dfnew['Yvalues']).to_frame()
    dfcorr.columns = ['correlation']
    # Calculate slope
    mask = ~np.isnan(dfnew.Xvalues) & ~np.isnan(dfnew.Yvalues)
    dfslope = dfnew.groupby('Company').apply(lambda v: 
    stats.linregress(v.Xvalues[mask], v.Yvalues[mask])[0]).to_frame()
    dfslope.columns = ['slope']
    # Join correlation and slop
    dffinal = dfcorr.join(dfslope, how='inner')
    dffinal['score'] = dffinal.correlation *((abs(dffinal.slope)+1)/2)
    # Add in date column
    dffinal['Date'] = dfnew.index.max()[0]
    # Set and reorder Index
    dffinal = dffinal.set_index('Date', append=True)
    dffinal = dffinal.reorder_levels(['Date','Company'])
    # Append results to new dataframe
    appended_data.append(dffinal)

# Concatenate dataframe
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```